Differentiate trackpad's buttons vs. Tap to click
I do not use the trackpad's 2 buttons. I do clicking by tap to click or clicking the whole trackpad. So I want to map the 2 buttons to something else. Autohotkey registers these 2 buttons as LButton and RButton. So I map:
LButton::Send "{Browser_Back}"

However, Autohotkey also registers tap to click or whole trackpad click as LButton. So tap to click or whole trackpad click are also changed.
Is there a way to differentiate between them?

From my understanding, what you are asking is for a tap and a click from a trackpad to be interpreted as different things. This will only be possible with AutoHotkey if the two actions have different scan codes. Try checking the scan codes of those two actions. If they have the same scan code, differentiating between the two of them would not be possible with AutoHotkey.

Do you mean the scan codes in View > Key History? If so then, yes all the clicks (button click, tap to click, whole trackpad click) show the same LButton.

Yes, I did mean the scan codes in View > Key History. If the clicks show as the same thing, AutoHotkey has no way to know that these clicks are from different sources. Because of this, you would be unable to create a program to fit your desires. I hope this helps!
